# Order of singularity - Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ have an isolated singularity at $z_0$. Define $$\text{ord} (f, z_0) = -\inf \{n \in \mathbb{N}: \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} (z-z_0)^n f(z) \hspace{2mm} \text{exists and is finite} \}$$

We then define a removable singularity as one that has $\text{ord} (f, z_0) \geq 0$.

However, I don't see why this is the case.

For example, take $$f(z) = \frac{\sin{z}}{z}$$ Then this has a removable singularity at $z=0$. But note that $$\inf \{n \in \mathbb{N}: \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} z^n \frac{\sin z}{z} \hspace{2mm} \text{exists and is finite} \} = 1 $$

And then the order is $-1$ which is not greater than or equal to zero??

Comment: $n=0$ works too so the order is zero; also the definition is weird as I think the infimum should be taken on integers

Comment: @Conrad oh right.... that was simple then. Do you have an example of a function with a removable singularity for which the order is positive?

Comment: If the inf is taken on natural numbers obviously the order is at most zero

Comment: If you take it on integers just do $\frac{\sin^2(z)}{z}$

Comment: I assume that the word "finite" in the definition means "non-zero". In this case only $n=0$ would work.